# Отображение layout вместо drawable в Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk, glide

Как через Glide в placeholder и error отобразить layout. По умолчанию он требует ресурс drawable, но мне нужно отобразить именно layout. Как можно это сделать? Если нельзя есть иные пути?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужо выбрать один из 3 путей. Вы не описали вашу задачу, засим можно лишь гадать какой именно вам лучше выбрать.

1. Скорее всего вам нужен просто слушатель ошибки загрузки, в котором вам надо скрывать/показывать вьюху с ошибкой:

   ```
    Glide.with(imageView)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(
            e: GlideException?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            // отобразите вьюху при ошибке
            return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(
            resource: Drawable,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            dataSource: DataSource?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            // картинка успешно загрузилась
            return false
        }
    })
    .into(imageView)
   ```
2. Либо сделайте таки картинку из вашей разметки вручную, поместите в ресурсы, и используйте как угодно.
3. Ещё можно программно превратить вьюху в `Bitmap` и её отображать в `ImageView`

Comment: во первый вариант то что нужно